# Relationship between mean and variance not removed after data transformation?

Tags: data-transformation, mean

I am a student and I am doing a research where I have a trait (lets say cow weight in kilograms) that presents a relationship between mean and variance. I also have a factor that is country/year (contemporary group). I plotted the mean versus variances for each contemporary group and I got the following equation: y = 1.23x + 0.01 and r2=0.57.

In the literature, the trait transformation recommended is:`weight adjusted = (animal weight/contemporary group mean)*global mean`, which is a proportion of contemporary group.

After transforming the data I plotted the mean for each contemporary group versus the variance for the adjusted weight. Now I observe an inverse relationship. The new equation is: y = -1.38 + 14.56 and r2 is: 0.43. I know that the new mean for the adjusted weight is the global mean. However, I would not expect this relationship. 
If I understood correctly, the groups with small mean now would have greater variances.

Just as an example for a different trait: The contemporary group 1 had originally a mean of 1.07 and variance of 2.03. After the adjustment, the mean would be 5 (global mean) and variance 44.01. Am I missing anything?

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it really needs more context, but the OP hasn't been seen for two years